# Change font size of ul element using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Here is the css:

```
#content ul {
               font-size: 12px;
           }
```

I am trying this:

```
document.getElementById("content ul").style.fontSize = 8px;
```

But this is not working for me. Can anybody suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Style properties are strings, so you need `"8px"` rather than `8px`.
2. [`getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) gets elements **by ID**. You're passing in a compound selector (and you're missing the `#` from it). You'll have to use an ID and then find the children (via [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D)), or use [`querySelector`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselector) (for the first matching element) or [`querySelectorAll`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall) (for all matching elements) instead. (Note that although well-supported in general, some older browsers don't have those last two; [details](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector).)

So for instance, here's how you would change the *first* matching element's font size on browsers with `querySelector` support:

```
document.querySelector("#content ul").style.fontSize = "8px";
```

Or all of them

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#content ul");
var index;
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    list[index].style.fontSize = "8px";
}
```

Or on older browsers:

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var list = content.getElementsByTagName("ul");
var index;
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    list[index].style.fontSize = "8px";
}
```

Comment: @NoviceMe: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

`<ul>'s` are elements, not id's. Get the content element by id first. Then get child nodes inside that are unordered lists. Finally iterate over the list and change the size. And as TJ said, you need to pass in a string.

```
var lists = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('ul');
for (var i; i < lists.length; i++ ) {
     lists[i].style.fontSize = '8px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select them properly. First you need to get the element that contains the `<ul>` in question.

```
var contentArea = document.getElementById("content");
```

Then you need to get the appropriate tags by tagname:

```
var tags = contentArea.getElementsByTagName("ul");
```

Then cycle through them to set the font size:

```
for (i=0; i<tags.length, i++)
{
    tags[i].style.fontSize = "8px"; // Don't forget the " here
}
```